# How DES oracle Decrypt equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, oracle, encryption, des

I have this function on oracle db :

```
BEGIN
    key_raw := utl_i18n.string_to_raw(key,'AL32UTF8');
    plaintext := dbms_crypto.decrypt(
    src => chipertext,
    typ => dbms_crypto.DES_CBC_PKCS5,
    key => key_raw
    );
    return utl_i18n.raw_to_nchar(plaintext,'AL32UTF8');
END
```

and need to implement in c# .Net

this what I've Done :

```
public static string DecryptDES(string strData,string skey)
        {
            byte[] clearData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strData);
            byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(skey);
            DES desDecrypt = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            desDecrypt.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            desDecrypt.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            desDecrypt.Key = key;
            ICryptoTransform transForm = desDecrypt.CreateDecryptor();
            MemoryStream decryptedStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(decryptedStream, transForm, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cryptoStream.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] plain = decryptedStream.ToArray();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plain);
        }
```

in oracle that function called like this :

```
select decrypt('BEB9B507432B91E116EC3F07364E38C5', 'testtesttest') from dual;
```

when this method call in c#:

```
DecryptDES("BEB9B507432B91E116EC3F07364E38C5", "testtesttest")
```

it's return error :

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.'
```

also I tried another key and chipertext and it's return bad data.

I believe this is something to do with data format, since it's return error on c#, any suggestion?

Comment: just edited, I forgot to add the last part

Comment: Ok thanks. but exactly what error does it return? We cannot just guess. Also please show how you call the c# method.

Comment: There are some problems in your code. I don't think it will compile like this. After some corrections, it may compile but will probably still yield runtime exceptions. Are you getting compile time errors?

* You cannot apply `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` on a string. You would have to use `GetBytes`

* You must provide DES with a key of size 64 bits. Given your example string, this will not work.

Comment: yes, just update, should be GetBytes instead of GetString,

Comment: when I change another key and chiper, it return System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Bad Data.
'
for this method call : 
DecryptDES("63509404D922F1D4CB2455314575E946", "02564808")

Comment: This most probably is a padding error. You are applying the PKCS7 padding, so the padding bytes are expected to be there when decrypting. Your input ciphertext is probably not the result of a previous encryption (but a random string?) so the padding bytes are most likely missing. You should try with a "real" ciphertext. Alternatively, try another padding mode.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is that your ciphertext input in C# is a string. Ciphertext (your `chipertext`, ugh) is binary (or "RAW" in Oracle speak). There should be no UTF-8 conversion to / from the ciphertext, because that may lead to missing data.

You'll probably have to use the first 7 or 8 bytes of the UTF-8 encoded key for DES. Yuk.

Comment: I also do convert that string to byte array, it means string "BE" become one byte data, but the decryption is not readable, I tried it with DecryptDES("63509404D922F1D4CB2455314575E946", "02564808")

Comment: here is the result in hex string 85FEE2B01AFA303838